# lfs gif file stopped showing on GitHub

Tags: github, git-lfs

I uploaded some gif files on GitHub with lfs tracking, because they were big. For a couple of hours, they were showing fine in my readme, but after I checked again they stopped showing. When I open the gif file, it shows something like:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:c91df1d2cc2933748a280654c31b4e8cb2aefce95677e9a777cedd63f67239af
size 2607602
```

Before that, I could see the gif, but now I can't. I tried re-uploading them, but it still acts the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, apparently GitHub offers 1GB of storage and 1GB of bandwidth free.
The storage increases when you add files with lfs tracking, and the bandwidth increases each time a file of this type is being downloaded (by the amount of storage said file takes) and also when the project is being cloned.
Here is some info:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/